# Zeppelin configuration properties file: Can't load BigQuery interpreter configuration

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-zeppelin

I am attempting to set my `zeppelin.bigquery.project_id` (or any bigquery configuration property) via my `zeppelin-site.xml`, but my changes are not loaded when I start Zeppelin. The project ID always defaults to ' '. I am able to change other configuration properties (ex. `zeppelin.notebook.storage`). I am using Zeppelin 0.7.3 from https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/zeppelin/.

zeppelin-site.xml (created before starting Zeppelin, before an `interpreter.json` file exists):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>zeppelin.notebook.storage</name>
    <value>org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.S3NotebookRepo</value>
    <description>notebook persistence layer implementation</description>
  </property>

  ... etc ...

  <property>
    <name>zeppelin.bigquery.project_id</name>
    <value>my-project-id</value>
    <description>Google Project Id</description>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Am I configuring the interpreter incorrectly? Could this parameter be overridden elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with Apache Zeppelin, but I have found some documentation pages that make me think that you should actually store the BigQuery configuration parameters in your Interpreter configuration file:

- This entry in the GCP blog explains [how to use the BigQuery Interpreter for Apache Zeppelin](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/09/analyzing-bigquery-datasets-using-bigquery-interpreter-for-apache-zeppelin). It includes some examples on how to use it with Dataproc, Apache Spark and the Interpreter.
- The [BigQuery Interpreter documentation for Zeppelin 0.7.3](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/bigquery.html) mentions that `zeppelin.bigquery.project_id` is the right parameter to configure, so that is not the issue here. Here there is some information on [how to configure the Zeppelin Interpreters](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/manual/interpreters.html#what-is-zeppelin-interpreter).
- The [GitHub page of the BigQuery Interpreter](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/tree/master/bigquery) states that you have to configure the properties during Interpreter creation, and then you should enable is by using `%bigquery.sql`.

Finally, make sure that you are specifying the BigQuery interpreter in the appropriate field in the `zeppelin-site.xml` (like done in [the template](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/conf/zeppelin-site.xml.template)) or instead [enable it by clicking on the "Gear" icon and selecting "bigquery"](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/bigquery.html#enabling-the-bigquery-interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/usr/lib/zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json`, change `zeppelin.bigquery.project_id` to be the value of your project and run `sudo systemctl restart zeppelin.service`.